# Ejemplo de un ViewModel usando Componente de Google en Android

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando implementar un `ViewModel` siguiendo ese [tutorial](http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/android-architecture-components-tutorial-room-livedata-viewmodel/) pero me parece que Google a renovado la librerías y ha dejado la mitad de código obsoleto.
Alguien tiene un ejemplo funcional y su instalación en las dependencias, uso Android Studio 3.0 con `target version 26`.

No me queda claro si tengo que cargar las dependencias de lyfecircle o no
[Adding Components to your Project](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html)

Solo necesito un ejemplo funcional una lista de items que al modificar pues se pueda interceptar con el `observer`

Comment: He encontrado un tutorial más actual https://medium.com/@taman.neupane/basic-example-of-livedata-and-viewmodel-14d5af922d0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para la instalación de los componentes de Google solo es necesario añadir al `app.gradle` la directiva
`implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0"`

Para crear un ViewModel(Presentador) extender de la clase `ViewModel`

Los datos que quieren ser observados definirlos con `MutableLiveData` si es una lista

`private MutableLiveData<List<String>> fruitList;`

Crear la función para recuperar la lista de datos

```
 LiveData<List<String>> getFruitList() {
    if (fruitList == null) {
        fruitList = new MutableLiveData<>();
        loadFruits();
    }
    return fruitList;
}
```

Para la tarea de llenado usar tareas de segundo plano, así se evita congelar la UI

```
private void loadFruits() {
    // do async operation to fetch users
    Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    myHandler.postDelayed(() -> {
        List<String> fruitsStringList = new ArrayList<>();
        fruitsStringList.add("Mango");
        fruitsStringList.add("Apple");
        fruitsStringList.add("Orange");
        fruitsStringList.add("Banana");
        fruitsStringList.add("Grapes");
        long seed = System.nanoTime();
        Collections.shuffle(fruitsStringList, new Random(seed));

        fruitList.setValue(fruitsStringList);
    }, 5000);

}
```

Para detectar que la actividad donde hay el observador se ha cerrado completamente, se usa el evento `onCleared`

```
@Override
protected void onCleared() {
    super.onCleared();
    Log.d(TAG, "on cleared called");
}
```

En la actividad para obtener los cambios de la lista y modificar la UI para mostrar los cambios

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(youViewModel.class);
        model.getFruitList().observe(this, fruitlist -> {
            // update UI from List List<String> fruitlist

        });
    }
```

Extraído de ese [tutorial en inglés](https://medium.com/@taman.neupane/basic-example-of-livedata-and-viewmodel-14d5af922d0)